# GCC API unable to demangle its own exported symbols

Tags: c++, gcc, abi, name-mangling

I’m trying to use [GCC’s `abi::__cxa_demangle`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) to demangle symbols exported from an object file that was produced by `g++`. However, I invariable get the error

> *mangled_name* is not a valid name under the C++ ABI mangling rules

Here’s how I call the function:

```
std::string demangled(std::string const& sym) {
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)>
        name{abi::__cxa_demangle(sym.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr), std::free};
    return {name.get()};
}
```

(Error handling omitted; it’s present in the [complete online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=50237014d5dcf0086314d1e164446ddc-13231fbb0c6cdea56c9bd7f1a9317b5b).)

The symbols I tested it with are obtained from this small code:

```
namespace foo {
    template <typename T>
    struct bar { bar() { } };
}

void baz(int x) { }

template struct foo::bar<int>;
```

via `g++ -c test.cpp; nm test.o | cut -d ' ' -f3`:

```
EH_frame1
__Z3bazi
__ZN3foo3barIiEC1Ev
__ZN3foo3barIiEC2Ev
```

I’m not really sure which purpose the GCC demangling API serves if it cannot demangle these symbols – it *can*, however, successfully demangle the C++ `typeid` representations. E.g. writing in the test code `typeid(foo::bar<int>*).name()` will yield `PN3foo3barIiEE`, which in turn is correctly demangled by the above function.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I demangle the exported symbols from a GCC object file?

Comment: If the object file targets ARM, say, then the name mangling scheme will be different. The fact that it's created by G++ does not guarantee a consistent name mangling scheme. However, what I'm really seeing is that those symbols have one too many underscores in front. Try cutting the front one off.

Comment: @DeadMG Interesting, didn’t know that, but in my case it isn’t actually ARM. Still, this might explain it. The questions remain: what is `__cxa_demangle` supposed to solve, and how do I demangle those symbols.

Comment: Exactly what are you "feeding" into the demangle function?

Comment: @Mats The names as I get them above (of course?).

Comment: With the `__` at the beginning, or without? I think it may make a difference...

Comment: on what platform are you? I can vaguely remember somthing about macosx prepending an extra _ that you need to strip

Comment: @PlasmaHH: My answer clearly shows that there is an extra _ here.

Comment: @DeadMG: But you also said: "I'm not sure why"

Comment: @Mats I tried both, actually. Neither works. I did *not* try removing just one leading underscore, as suggested by PlasmaHH. Hmm. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your symbols have one too many underscores in front. I'm not sure why, but if you check [C++filtjs](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/), it reports the same thing- they are not valid Itanium ABI symbols with two underscores in front but are with just one. In this case, I would say that the output of `nm` is incorrect, not that the demangle function is wrong. The Itanium ABI specifies and I know that Clang uses just one underscore.

Y'know, it really says something that I can almost read Itanium ABI mangled names by now. Way too much time reading Clang's LLVM IR output.